# Add A clear div every 3rd foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I want to add a clear `div` (that is, `<div class="clear></div>`) after every 3rd term, but I am having difficulties doing this within a `foreach` block. I can, however, within a while loop.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 

$terms = get_field('feature_choices');
// print_r($terms);
if( $terms ): ?>

<?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>

    <div class="col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/checkmark.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <?php echo $term->name; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You'll want to use [`mod`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php)

Comment: Add a counter variable before the loop and add 1 to it each time in your loop. Then use $counter % 3 == 0 to see if it's each third repetition. Then add in what you want to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a counter

```
<?php $count = 1; foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>

    <div class="col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/checkmark.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <?php echo $term->name; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php if( $count % 3 == 0 ) echo "\n".'<div class="clear"></div>'; ?>
<?php $count++; endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```